# Qt-append deminal part of float number to long varibale

Tags: qt, qstring

I have `unsigned long a=999999999;`
and `float b=0.123456;`
and i want to have result in `QString` as `999999999.123456` what is best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Below is one of the way. (but i don't know whether this way is best or not).

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    unsigned long ulng=999999999UL;
    float flt=0.123456F;

    //format 'f' meaning given below
    QString str = QString::number((double)ulng+flt,'f');
    std::cout << "Total = " << str.toStdString() << std::endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

**Total = 999999999.123456**

[**Format   Meaning**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QString.html#argument-formats)

> e format as [-]9.9e[+|-]999
>   E format as [-]9.9E[+|-]999
>   f format as [-]9.9
>   g use e or f format, whichever is the most concise
>   G use E or f format, whichever is the most concise